# Save wordpad to HTML?

Tags: html, rtf, wordpad

Is there any way to save MS WordPad files (basically RTF) as HTML?

I edited a document, made all my styles now I want to save it as HTML, is there anyway (add-in or extension?) to save it as HTML right from wordpad instead of looking for an online free tool that does it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) opens RTF documents and exports to HTML. You can download compiled binaries for many platforms from the site.

I have never tested it, but the RTF option is present in the Open File dialogue. Exporting to HTML has looked reasonable when I have tried it in the past, but I have never had strong feelings about the styles so I can't vouch for the fidelity.

### Edit:

I happened to type `eix rtf` in a terminal just now (for an unrelated purpose), and a number of items you may be interested in popped up. Abridged list:

> - app-text/rtf2html
>      Homepage:            http://rtf2html.sourceforge.net/
>      Description:         RTF to HTML converter.
>      License:             LGPL-2.1
> - app-text/unrtf
>      Homepage:            http://www.gnu.org/software/unrtf/unrtf.html
>      Description:         Converts RTF files to various formats
>      License:             GPL-2
> - dev-python/rtf2xml
>      Homepage:            http://rtf2xml.sourceforge.net/
>      Description:         Converts a Microsoft RTF file to structured XML
>      License:             GPL-2

Of these, rtf2html version 0.19.3 and 0.20.1 are considered stable by Gentoo.

Comment: Good answer, though it's worth pointing out that word processors always generate really terrible HTML. Though I don't suppose @Shimmy really cares that if he started out writing his document in WordPad.

Comment: Would probably be better to retype it in notepad or notepad++

Comment: I was actually looking for a WYSIWYG HTML editor, and the first 5 or so results out there in Google were pure crap. I ended up editing my file in WordPad, thinking there is a built-in inversion to HTML, then I thought maybe there is some sort of add-in, but I now see there isn't. So if you know of a good free online WYSIWYG editor, please lemme know about it ([this](http://htmleditor.in) is crap for instance, and [this](http://www.free-online-html-editor.com/) one doesn't work in Chrome)

Comment: It's not online, but [Lyx](http://www.lyx.org) is a nice editor for structured documents. It uses Latex as it's back-end, and supports importing from many formats and exporting to HTML and many other formats.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading [RTFConverter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter), then use using the command line application *Rtf2Html.exe* in the `bin\release` folder.

You should be able to mass convert your files easily this way, although as with all automated conversions be sure to visually confirm that the final results look similar to the original sources.

Of course, if you have Word installed you can use it as well (even automate it using a macro or VBScript), but don't expect great things in terms of HTML quality.

Answer (score 0):

Open your WordPad document: Launch WordPad on your computer and open the document you want to save as HTML.

Click on "File": In the top-left corner of the WordPad window, click on the "File" menu.

Select "Save As": From the drop-down menu that appears, click on "Save As."

Choose the save location: Navigate to the location on your computer where you want to save the HTML file.

Enter the file name: Type the desired name for your HTML file in the "File name" field. Make sure to end the filename with the ".html" extension, for example, "example.html."

Answer (score -1):

If you are on a PC the best option is to just copy and paste all your code into 'Notepad' that allows you to save the file as .html

If on a mac there are a few free text editors that allow the user to save in a .html file format.

I have found that a good way to code and save files is the Cloud 9 IDE. It is internet based easy to use with live preview options. The files are saved on the cloud therefore be used on any computer anywhere and can be saved to your computer.